# How to make CSS shape crop itself to fit browser window instead of making it wider

Tags: css, z-index, css-shapes

Maybe this question was already asked, but it's really hard to find anything with my low tier vocabulary :(.

```css
.first {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  border-radius: 125px;
  top: -100px;
  left: 800px;
  z-index: -2500;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="bg1">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make this giant shape to fit browser window, instead of making entire page wider. I want it to be cropped on top and right side, so only the other half would be visible to me.

Effect i'm trying to achieve looks like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNEKY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.first {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}

.bg1 {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 50px;
background: #333;
position: fixed;
top: -30px;
right: -100px;
transform: rotate(75deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="bg1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MichałKotowski If it helps upvote & accept this answer :-)

Comment: I will, no worries :)